# jQuery - the usage of $('#' + id)

Tags: jquery

I just came across `$('#' + id).empty().hide();` that resets some code block of jquery.
I don't understand the purpose of concatenating `id` with the `#` rather than
just referencing the whole id as `#('#something')`.

I suppose there is a good reason for it so I am curious to know.
Your two cents will be appreciated.

**EDIT**

Below is the demo I was talking about.
I should have said that I understand `id` here is used as a variable but the thing I don't get is what value this `id` is referenced from.

```
var demobox = $('#' + id);
var fields = $('#jq4u-demo-form').serializeArray(),
    fieldDetails;
demobox.empty();
$.each(fields, function (i, field) {
    demobox.append(field.name + '=' + field.value + '<br/>');
});
```

Comment: Because the jQuery id selector starts with `#`.

Comment: I know id starts with `#` and class with `.`....that's not the point of discussion here.

Comment: jQuery uses the CSS Selector Engine to select elements when available, else it uses sizzle. This is why jquery selectors match what you would see in a css stylesheet.

Comment: What's the value of `id`?

Comment: jQuery, as in the function `$()`, accepts a string, and having a leading `#` in that string means it's an ID, and jQuery will search for elements with a matching ID. This also means you can add any string, even a variable, but it must start with `#` to search for an ID, so `# + id` is just a string.

Comment: @SeongLee Based on your edit, the answer would be to make the id variable. Of course if the id is **always** `something` (for example), then there wouldn't be a difference.

Comment: Surely you know there's a difference between '#' + id and '#id', right?  The former uses the value of a variable, e.g. if `var id = 'foo';` then '#' + id = '#foo', while '#id' = '#id'

Comment: @JasonP Please see my edit. I'm just not sure what value this `id` holds.

Comment: @SeongLee Just alert the var (see my answer).  You can also use `console.log(id)` to see output in console without popping-up a msgbox.

Answer (score 1):

It is written that way because the name of the element is stored in a variable.

If you hard-code the selector, you would write:

```
$('#something').empty().hide();
```

However, suppose the name of the element is stored in a text field called `#hide_this_one`. Suppose you grab the value of that text field and assign it to a variable called `id`. Now, the variable `id` has the name of the control `something`:

```
var id = $('#hide_this_one').val();
$('#'+id).empty().hide();
```

Will empty and hide the control `#something`.

---

Answering your additional question:

You can know what control is being referenced here:

```
var demobox = $('#' + id);
```

by adding this additional code (just for testing):

```
var demobox = $('#' + id);
alert(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand the purpose of concatenating `id` with the `#` rather than just referencing the whole id as `#('#something')`.

The purpose in that case would be the `something` part of that selector changes based on the value of `id`, allowing you to reuse it by simply passing a different id.